# after importing spring-aspects,some controller not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I write 2 controllers--GoodController and UserController, after importing spring-aspects, my UserController url 404, but GoodController is normal, I can't find the reason and don't know how to resolve. All my pom.xml is bellow:

project parent pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>top.lovely6</groupId>
        <artifactId>user</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.43</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--shiro-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--shiro-web-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--shiro-spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--shiro缓存-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0  </version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- swagger生成接口API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 接口API生成html文档 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- StringUtils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log :slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--json:fastjson-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.47</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

user module pom.xml:-- no dependency

good module pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>top.lovely6</groupId>
        <artifactId>user</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>top.lovely6</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ApplicationStarter module pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>top.lovely6</groupId>
        <artifactId>good</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>top.lovely6</groupId>
        <artifactId>user</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

common module pom.xml:-- no dependency

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@EnableSwagger2
public class UserController {
    @Resource
    private UserService userService;

    @RequiresRoles("admin")
    @RequiresPermissions("create")
    @PostMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setCreateTime(new Date());
        userService.save(user);
        System.out.print(user);
        return user;
    }
    //...
}
```

and GoodController is almost same as UserController.

log aop config:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class SysLogAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(top.lovely6.annotation.SysLog)")
    public void logPointCut() {
    }

    @Around("logPointCut()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //执行方法
        Object result = point.proceed();
        //执行时长(毫秒)
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;

        log.info(time.toString());

        return result;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: You are mixing versions of a framework never do that. Remove the plain `spring-test`, `spring-aop` and `spring-context-support` dependencies. Those are already managed elsewhere and add `spring-boot-starter-aop` . Your `spring-boot-starter-test` should be scoped with `test` and remove the plain `JUnit` dependency. Also remove `commons-logging`, Spring has a replacement for that to properly route the logging.

Comment: Thank you so much. After using your method, the problem is still exist, and when I annotate “@RequiresRoles” and other shiro permission annotations, it worked, but   I still confuse about that. Would you explain it for me?

Comment: I found a blog.   https://blog.csdn.net/WatsonYee/article/details/81349209